# axios put not happening throwing forbidden

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, axios

- I am new to axios.

  - I am trying to do an update to my api through put request. But I am getting the below error.
    OPTIONS http://t/Sports/1 403 (Forbidden)
  - I am researched so many sites for axios but still I am not able to fix the issue
  - can you tell me how to fix it.
  - providing my code snippet below

```or-tag-here
<div className={classes.SportsEditTabContentFooter}>

    <div>Sports Status</div>
    <div>
        <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button}>
        Cancel
                </Button>
        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={this.saveSports} className={classes.button}>
        Save Sports test
                </Button>
    </div>
</div>

  saveSports = () => {
    console.log("saveSports---->");
    console.log(this.state.Sports);
    let saveSports = this.state.Sports;
    saveSports.updatedBy = 'raj';
    saveSports.priceRuleDescription = "test description";

    axios
      .put(
      'http://t/Sports/' + saveSports.SportsID,
      saveSports,
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
      )
      .then(r => console.log(r))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

    //this.toggleDrawer("right", false);
    this.setState({ right: false });
    this.setState({ snackBarOpen: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ snackBarOpen: false });
    }, 6000)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you try communicating different domain because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) browser automatically sends OPTIONS request. And backend does not expect this so it returns 403 for whatever reason.

Having this in mind your need

1. either change your client code to make [request simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests)
2. place your client code to be run on the same domain where backend runs
3. run CORS proxy server as the same domain where client code is hosted - since OPTIONS aka preflight request is sent just by browser your code in, say, Node, does not require that
4. update target backend code to handle preflight OPTIONS request correctly

Each variant is enough to solve your issue. But it's up to you to decide what is more convenient in your case

PS just in case: no, there is no way to avoid preflight OPTIONS request to be sent by configuring axios, replacing axios with different package, `fetch()` call or native `XmlHttpRequest` or any other easy change in your client code since it's fundamental (security!) feature of modern web browsers

Comment: do you have any demo where I can refer it